# Find x,y coordinate of Dataframe.plot.kde()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scipy

- I am trying to identify the peak coordinates (x,y) of a kde/gaussian
  curve
- How can I get the **X** values and **Y** values from
  losing_mae.plot.kde(...) so that I can get the argmax()

[image]

```
losing_mae.tail(10)

238    -500.0
239    -637.5
240    -412.5
242   -1062.5
243    -562.5
245    -412.5
247    -437.5
252    -800.0
254    -662.5
255   -1062.5
Name: mae, Length: 113, dtype: float64

losing_mae.hist(ax=ax, bins=25, color='c', alpha=0.5)

losing_mae.plot.kde(color='c', ax=ax2, lw=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

losing_mae = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({1: {0: -500.0,
      1: -637.5,
      2: -412.5,
      3: -1062.5,
      4: -562.5,
      5: -412.5,
      6: -437.5,
      7: -800.0,
      8: -662.5,
      9: -1062.5}}
```

The `kde` plot returns an [`axes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html) object. You can drill down to find the x and y:

```
d = losing_mae.plot.kde()
print(d.get_children())
```

Which gives a list of the objects. You probably want to drill down into the `Line2D`:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fb82ce67550>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fb82d237e80>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fb84003cd30>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fb82d221b38>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fb82d221748>,
 <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x7fb82d2590f0>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x7fb82d221400>,
 Text(0.5, 1.0, ''),
 Text(0.0, 1.0, ''),
 Text(1.0, 1.0, ''),
 <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7fb82ce67400>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x7fb82cea6940>]
```

Now grab the line and its `path` and then you can get the `vertices`:

```
l = d.get_children()[0].get_path()
l = l.vertices
print(l)

array([[-1.38750000e+03,  5.87608940e-05],
       [-1.38619870e+03,  5.97906082e-05],
       [-1.38489740e+03,  6.08341884e-05],
       ....  # and so on for ~2000 points
```

Separate the X and Y:

```
x, y = np.split(l.vertices, 2, 1)
```

And then you can just call `max` on both to get the points you want:

```
peakX, peakY = x.max(), y.max()
print(peakX, peakY)
87.5 0.0015392054229208412
```

Comment: This is exactly was I was looking for. Did not know that you can get the verticals from the plot object. Very useful to know

Comment: The following get the x coordinate from above example: x[y.argmax()]